# hive insert overwrite directory only overwrite direct path of generated file not the directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, cloudera-cdh

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -ls /mytest/warehouse/mytable/

Found 4 items
-------------

 - -rwxrwxrwx 3 myvm users 1163 2016-11-24 03:11 /mytest/warehouse/mytable/000000_0
 - -rwxrwxrwx 3 myvm users 0 2016-11-24 03:09 /mytest/warehouse/mytable/000000_1
 - -rwxrwxrwx 3 myvm users 0 2016-11-24 03:09 /mytest/warehouse/mytable/000000_2
 - -rwxrwxrwx 3 myvm users 0 2016-11-24 03:09 /mytest/warehouse/mytable/000000_3
```

### QUESTION

```
insert overwrite directory "/mytest/warehouse/mytable" select * from my_table
```

Above command will only overwrite the file it is generating that is: `/mytest/warehouse/mytable/000000_0`

I expected it to remove all the files under the path and create 1 file with the desired output.

It seems to be working fine before going for `hive-1.1.0-cdh5.5.1`.

Comment: I'm using Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.1 and I can't reproduce this behavior. After executing "insert overwrite directory" everything that previously happened to be in that directory gets deleted.

Comment: When the "select" command produces only 1 file(000000_0) and the output directory has more than 1 file(000000_0,000000_1,000000_2,000000_3), it will overwrite only the file which it creates(000000_0). I suspect its a bug in cdh5.5.1. But could not get any jira request for it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

it is generating 4 part files because your number of reducers are 4 . for generating only one part file in output

you can set hive property in your hive terminal

> `set mapred.reduce.tasks=1`

also

Number of reducers depends also on size of the input file

By default it is 1GB (1000000000 bytes). You could change that by setting the property hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer:

either by changing hive-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
   <value>1000000</value>
</property>
```

or using set

$ hive -e "set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=1000000"

Comment: Thanks Rijul for the answer. I wanted multiple files to be created as Its my application need. I wanted to know why insert overwrite is not working as expected. Wasnt it supposed to overwrite all the files in the directory before writing new data in it.